# Why is the centre of a circle: $(x + a)^2 + (y + b)^2 = c^2$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

1. Why is the centre of the circle:

   $$(x + a)^2 + (y + b)^2 = c^2,$$

$(-a,-b)$?

---

2. What is a good way of remembering that the centre of the circle:

   $$(x + a)^2 + (y + b)^2 = c^2$$

is $(-a,-b)$ and not $(a,b)$?

Comment: The center of $(x-(-a))^2+(y-(-b))^2=c^2$ is $(-a,-b)$, just as the center of $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$ is $(a,b)$

Comment: Right. Why is that true?

Comment: distance from $(x,y)$ to $(a,b)$ is $c$

Comment: It might be useful to remember that in just *one* dimension, the distance between two points on the number line is (the absolute value of) their difference, not their sum. For instance, if you have a point at $a = -2$, and another point at $b = 4$, then the distance between them is $|a - b| = |4 - (-2)| = 6$, not $|4 + (-2)| = 2$. In fact, we could express the distance $c$ between them using the equation $c^2 = (a-b)^2$, and it would be perfectly valid. We only normally don't do that because in one dimension, it isn't necessary. But it would make the generalization to $n$ dimensions clearer.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: OK, I can put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation relating points lying on the circle centre $(a,b)$ and radius $c$ is given by
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=c$$
where the left hand side gives the **distance of the point $(x,y)$ from the centre** and the right hand side gives the radius. For the distance from point $(x,y)$ the centre to be equal to $0$ we need $(x,y)=(a,b)$ hence the coordinates of the centre must be $(a,b)$. The equation above can be rewritten as
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$$
$$(x+(-a))^2+(y+(-b))^2=c^2$$
which gives the same form you mention.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to remember that in just *one* dimension, the distance between two points on the number line is (the absolute value of) their difference, not their sum. For instance, if you have a point at $a = -2$, and another point at $b = 4$, then the distance between them is $|b - a| = |4 - (-2)| = 6$, not $|4 + (-2)| = 2$.

[image]

In fact, we could express the distance $c$ between them using the equation $c = \sqrt{(a-b)^2}$, and it would be perfectly valid. We only normally don't do that because in one dimension, it isn't necessary. But it would make the generalization to $n$ dimensions clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The euclidean distance  from the point $M(x,y)$ to the point $C(a,b)$ is the length of the vector
$$\overrightarrow{CM}=\overrightarrow{OM}-\overrightarrow{OC}=x\,\vec i+y\,\vec j-(a\,\vec i+b\,\vec j)=(x-a)\,\vec i+(y-b)\,\vec j;$$
whence the formula for the length in an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead say that the centre of circle $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$$
is $(a,b)$.

Notice how this substitution requires $c^2=0\implies c=0$.

Comment: I don't understand this.  The *radius* of the circle is $(a, b)$?  Do you mean that if one considers the degenerate "circle" that consists of just that point $(a, b)$, the radius is required to be $0$?

Comment: You shouldn't, because I'm an idiot who can't proofread. Corrected

Comment: And yes, that is the conclusion I am drawing ultimately